# How to by-pass verify pip RHEL 7.6?

Tags: python, ssl, pip, pem

I need to install a component using PIP Version 20! I already downloaded the package: https://pypi.org/search/?q=resilient-circuits
But it points error because it needs to perform the SSL check and cannot validate the certificate:

```
root@<machine>resadmin]# pip install resilient_circuits-35.0.203.tar.gz
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

Processing ./resilient_circuits-35.0.203.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

 command: /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-IZErxn/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-IZErxn/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-req-build-IZErxn/pip-egg-info

     cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-IZErxn/

Complete output (26 lines):

Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools_scm/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727) -- Some packages may not be found!

Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools-scm/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727) -- Some packages may not be found!

Couldn't find index page for 'setuptools_scm' (maybe misspelled?)

Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727) -- Some packages may not be found!

No local packages or working download links found for setuptools_scm

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-req-build-IZErxn/setup.py", line 83, in <module>

    'resilient-circuits = resilient_circuits.bin.resilient_circuits_cmd:main']

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 335, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 456, in fetch_build_eggs

    replace_conflicting=True,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 863, in resolve

    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1141, in best_match

    return self.obtain(req, installer)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1153, in obtain

    return installer(requirement)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 522, in fetch_build_egg

    return cmd.easy_install(req)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 666, in easy_install

    raise DistutilsError(msg)

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setuptools_scm')
```

---

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)'),)) - skipping
```

Would there be any way to by-pass this?

Comment: In [so] only post questions in English.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site. Please translate your question or ask on [pt.so] instead.

Comment: Now that this is in English (good work), you will have to explain more and provide more details. Only then people will vote to  reopen this question.